# AlamoFire installation not building

Tags: xcode, swift, rest, afnetworking, alamofire

## AlamoFire won't build

So, I am trying to install AlamoFire on my Xcode  project, did everything that the site told me "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire", and it will just not build

I've tried using CocoaPods and its Pods files, didn't work also.

**And it gives me this**

[image]

Anyone also having this?? Could anyone help me??:)

Comment: If you are using CocoaPods can you show us your podfile ?